# Vue router firebase auth guard doesn't work

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-authentication, vue-router

I have a simple route guard with firebase authentication but it doesn't work as it is supposed to.

The code below doesn't render anything and it doesn't show any console errors.

So, I didn't implement any auth system in my app for now, so, it suppose to redirect to /auth route and show the Auth.vue content but it doesn't show anything, just a blank page.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Auth.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="auth">
    <h1>Auth</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import Auth from './views/Auth.vue'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'

Vue.use(Router)

let router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        auth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/auth',
      name: 'auth',
      component: Auth
    }
  ]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.auth)) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (!user) {
        next('/auth');
      } else {
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

`if(!user)
    {
      next({
        path: '/auth'
      })
    }`

instead of

`if (!user) {
        next('/auth');
      }`

Comment: thanks for reply but it doesn't help either, route doesn't change and nothing renders

Comment: This is how i have it in my current Project `router.beforeEach((to,from,next) => {
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.auth)){
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if(!user)
    {
      next({
        path: '/'
      })
    } else {
      next() 
    }
  })}else next()    
})`  Could you show me your App.vue please?

Comment: @YegorGunko Okay, i can´t see any errors in the example, could you show the main.js file maybe i see something there because the Router Code itself seems fine.

Comment: @YegorGunko Okay, but where do you initialize your firebase connection? It should look like this [this](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*8GheSto8finV8_SVcnWJwA.png)

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry, I forgot to import firebase.js file with my init

Comment: @YegorGunko Ok im glad i could help, have fun with your project :)